# Delete IE Cache Programatically in 64 bit OS

Tags: c#, wininet

How can I delete the IE cache in a 64 bit environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After contacting the MSFT support the answer turned out to be that I had to run the application under an interactive user. It seems like wininet on win 08 64 bit did not like executing the delete cache apis under a non interactive user!

Comment: non interactive user? you mean a service? WinInet, IE's networking library, isn't supported in windows service.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [How to clear the cache when your application hosts a WebBrowser control in Visual C# .NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/326201)

Comment: no error... it just seems like is not working... the following directory continues to grow in size “\windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files\Content.IE5"

Comment: this is the x86 folder, you need to compile you application in x86 mode in order that the api will refer to that folder.
In the build choose x86 instead of AnyCpu.